# Rails - getting an error when creating a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `create_remember_token' for #<User:0x007f1e984596c0>
```

Here is a link to my code: https://gist.github.com/Veske/7544853

Should have everything there, but when I create a user, it gives me that error. No problem making one via console tough.

Comment: Obviously there's no `create_remember_token` anywhere in your gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `create_remember_token` method in your `User` model.

It's clearly written in [Michael Hartl's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-remember_me) tutorial:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :create_remember_token

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```